# Reliably ingesting a CSV file where a value can be a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, csv

I am parsing CSV files where values include strings that represent JSON objects, among boolean, normal strings, and other values. The CSV file has a header. As I iterate over the non-header rows of the CSV file, I use Javascript's split method with the following regex to grab the value at each 'cell' of the CSV row:

```
let currentLine = lines[i].split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't always delimit lines containing legal JSON strings. Some strings are captured, but strings like this one gets truncated in odd places, wrecking the parsing of the entire CSV file:

```
'{"an object" : [{"sub-object 1": {
    "description": "sub-object is for blah blah",
    "nestedArray": ["param1","param2","param3"]}},
  {"sub-object 2": {
    "description": "sub-object is for blah blah",
    "nestedArray": ["param1","param2","param3"]}},
  {"sub-object 3": {
    "description": "sub-object is for blah blah",
    "nestedArray": ["param1","param2","param3"]}}
  ]
}'
```

As far as I can tell, the above is legal JSON (curiously, https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# validates the above if it's pasted *without* single quotes surrounding it -- not sure why that would be). Any thoughts on how to properly parse this? I thought this would be a fairly trivial task but apparently JSON is not frequently embedded as a value in CSV files. Not sure if there's a standard or best practices way of handling this.

EDIT: To clarify, if anyone has a regex that would capture the above json string in a CSV file, I'd be greatly appreciated if you could share it with me

Comment: JSON does not use single quotes which is why parsers throw a syntax error when given the above snippet

Comment: The problem is in your regex. You can't parse a CSV line using split. Its impossible. It doesn't matter what the _fields_ contain.

Comment: Just my 2 cents. Somehow the idea to include JSON in CSV files sounds like a terrible one.  If the purpose is to export objects, then just use json files.

Comment: @LukStorms, I'm inclined to agree with you, though I want to see if it's possible (this is for work).

Comment: @sln, that would be much appreciated -- I'll update the post accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This can be used as a template for general purpose CSV parsing.

```
(?:(?:^|,|\r?\n)[^\S\r\n]*)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|[^,\r\n]*)(?:[^\S\r\n]*(?=$|,|\r?\n)))
```

test: https://regex101.com/r/AnQqyv/1
Where the field is trimmed in capture group 1

```
 (?:                           # Delimiter comma or newline
    (?: ^ | , | \r? \n )
    [^\S\r\n]*                    # leading optional whitespaces
 )
 (?:
    (                             # (1 start), field
       "                             # " Quoted
       [^"\\]* 
       (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
       "
     |                              # or
       '                             # ' Quoted
       [^'\\]* 
       (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
       '
     |                              # or
       [^,\r\n]*                     # Non-quoted
    )                             # (1 end)
    (?:
       [^\S\r\n]*                    # trailing optional whitespaces 
       (?= $ | , | \r? \n )          # Delimiter ahead, comma or newline
    )
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I'll give this a try!

Comment: @ChrisT - You could use a callback in th JS regex search to put the group 1 vals into an array and trim any quotes as well. There are many variants of csv parsing using regex as well.